# How do I build a sum report to feed a Salesforce gas gauge dashboard?

Tags: salesforce, dashboard

I'm trying to build what I think would be a simple report to feed a salesforce gas gauge dashboard component.

The end goal is to have a goal amount (easy enough to set in the formatting parameters of the gas gauge component) that moves the needle based on the sum of an "amounts" field in closed opportunities.

No matter how I group the reports the only options for a value in the "Component Data" tab of the gas guage itself are: Auto, Average Age, and Record Count... all pretty useless for what I'm trying to do. What I really want to use is the total amount... a sum.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The groups available on the dashboards are based on the summarised fields within the report.

It sounds like your report summarises the age (and the standard Record Count), but there is no summary involving the Amount field.

Go to your report and summarise the Amount field.  You can do this by clicking the down arrow next to the 'Amount' column and select the 'Summarize this field'.  Once it's summarised, it should appear as an option on your gauge.

Comment: Thank you... it wasn't obvious to me (when I was trying to figure it out) because you have to hover over that field to get the drop down summary/filter options menu. I appreciate the help, that did the trick!